# How to add a user tracking button to MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mkmapview

I would like to add a button on a MKMapView to move the map to the current user location. I saw this icon on plenty of applications :

[image: Google Maps' Button]

Is there any class for this ? Or should I create it myself ? I know I can use `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` but I don't wan't to use a Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try - myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES ?

Comment: This will show a blue "pin" on the map on my current location, but no moving the map to my location such as this icon

Answer (score 0):

Add the button/image however you like and when you want to move to the user's location, call this method:

```
- (void)zoomToUserLocation {
    // create a region object with the user's location as the center coordinate, and some
    // arbitrary value you'd like as the region span (.005 is one I use regularly)
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005));
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
}
```